# Concatenating multiple files into a single line in linux

Tags: awk, concatenation, fasta

I have 3 fasta files like following

```
>file_1_head
haszhaskjkjkjkfaiezqbsga    
>file_1_body
loizztzezzqieovbahsgzqwqoiropoqiwoioioiweoitwwerweuiruwieurhcabccjashdja    
>file_1_tail
mnnbasnbdnztoaosdhgas
```

I would like to concatenate them into a single like following

```
>file_1
haszhaskjkjkjkfaiezqbsgaloizztzezzqieovbahsgzqwqoiropoqiwoioioiweoitwwerweuiruwieurhcabccjashdjamnnbasnbdnztoaosdhgas
```

I tried with cat command `cat file_1_head.fasta file_1_body.fasta file_1_tail.fasta` but it didnt concatenates into a single line like above. Is it possible with "awk" Kindly guide me.

Comment: This is a trivial task. What have you tried to solve it on your own?

Comment: @hek2mgl What I have tried I have mentioned in my question. I tried with "cat" command but it just puts all the lines in a new line. Kindly check it

Comment: Yeah, I read that. But I miss something that you've tried to *solve* the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean your three files have the content

**file_1_head.fasta**

```
>file_1_head
haszhaskjkjkjkfaiezqbsga
```

**file_1_body.fasta**

```
>file_1_body
loizztzezzqieovbahsgzqwqoiropoqiwoioioiweoitwwerweuiruwieurhcabccjashdja
```

and **file_1_tail.fasta**

```
>file_1_tail
mnnbasnbdnztoaosdhgas
```

including the name of each of them within them as the first line?

Then you could do

```
(echo ">file_1"; tail -qn -1 file_1_{head,body,tail}.fasta | tr -d "\n\t ") > file_1.fasta
```

to get **file_1.fasta** as

```
>file_1
haszhaskjkjkjkfaiezqbsgaloizztzezzqieovbahsgzqwqoiropoqiwoioioiweoitwwerweuiruwieurhcabccjashdjamnnbasnbdnztoaosdhgas
```

This also removes some extra whitespace at the end of the lines in your input that I got when I copied them verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply with

```
cat file1 file2 file3 | tr -d '\n' > new_file
```

`tr` deletes the newline character.

EDIT:

For your specific first line just do

```
echo file_1 > new_file
cat file1 file2 file3 | tr -d '\n' >> new_file
```

The first command creates the file with one line `file_1` in it. Then the `cat...` command just appends to this file.

Comment: Thanks. But your command gives  me output like following  >file_1haszhaskjkjkjkfaiezqbsgaloizztzezzqieovbahsgzqwqoiropoqiwoioioiweoitwwerweuiruwieurhcabccjashdjamnnbasnbdnztoaosdhgas. I want the output like above mentioned

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: It gave me output like following: file_1                                                                                                         >file_1_headhaszhaskjkjkjkfaiezqbsga>file_1_bodyloizztzezzqieovbahsgzqwqoiropoqiwoioioiweoitwwerweuiruwieurhcabccjashdja>file_1_tailmnnbasnbdnztoaosdhgas

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to explain more clearly what you want and how you're doing it at the moment. Is the file_1_head content in the file? And you don't want lines starting with `>` or what? I need details. If it is like this, you can skip those lines with `cat file1 file2 file3 | grep -v "^>" | tr ...`

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS=""} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { printf "%s",$i } }' f1_head f1_body f1_tail
```